# I'm new to SQL Server and I'm trying to create a report which will knock 10% off an invoice total

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure which I can use to create a report to show a customer's invoice plus temporary columns (I don't want these to actually be in tables just on the report) for corporate discount(-10%) and a total which is invoice amount - 10%.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInvoice10incTotal]
(@invoiceid INT)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT     
      dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number, dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Date, 
      dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount, dbo.Customer.CustomerID, 
      dbo.Customer.First_Name, dbo.Customer.Last_Name, 
      (dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.1) AS Corporate_Discount 
   FROM         
      dbo.Customer 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Invoices ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Invoices.CustomerID
   WHERE 
      dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number = @invoiceid 

   SELECT     
      dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number, dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Date, 
      dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount, dbo.Customer.CustomerID, 
      dbo.Customer.First_Name, dbo.Customer.Last_Name, 
      (dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount - Corporate_Discount) AS Total 
   FROM         
      dbo.Customer 
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.Invoices ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Invoices.CustomerID
   WHERE 
      dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number = @invoiceid 
END

/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
RETURN
```

Comment: And what is your trouble?

Comment: Hi its coming up as 2 separate queries when i execute the code rather than a single one with all the details on. The first shows the corporate discount and the second shows the total(as Null) but no corporate discount.

Comment: FYI, you should add a discount field on your customer table in case you need to have different discounts per customer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number ,
        dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Date ,
        dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount ,
        dbo.Customer.CustomerID ,
        dbo.Customer.First_Name ,
        dbo.Customer.Last_Name ,
        dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.1 AS Corporate_Discount ,
        dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount - dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.1 AS Total
FROM    dbo.Customer
        INNER JOIN dbo.Invoices ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Invoices.CustomerID
WHERE   dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number = @invoiceid
```

Comment: Why not use "dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.9" instead of "dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount - dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge two queries by using UNION, but that is probably not what you are after (also you can't use an alias from the first query in the second).

It looks like you'd rather expand this horizontally (adding columns) through one query, like:

```
SELECT dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number, 
dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Date, 
dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount, 
dbo.Customer.CustomerID, 
dbo.Customer.First_Name, 
dbo.Customer.Last_Name, 
(dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.1) AS Corporate_Discount,
(dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount - (dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Amount * 0.1)) AS Total 
FROM dbo.Customer INNER JOIN
dbo.Invoices ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Invoices.CustomerID
WHERE dbo.Invoices.Invoice_Number=@invoiceid
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys much appreciated, it makes more sense when i actually read the suggestions. Can't believe i didn't think of *0.9 instead of *0.1. Cheers